# How can we distribute an iOS Application using iOS Developer Enterprise program?

Tags: ios, iphone, enterprise

I have developed an iPhone Application and i am using an Enterprise Program for this. I have experienced with iOS developer program. For testing purpose, generally i have used TestFlight & shared the App link with our testers. Now i need to share an app with multiple employees.

My question is -

How can i deliver this application in 3000 employees using an Enterprise program ?

Should i have to share an app link with all ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

http://www.apple.com/business/accelerator/

This is a quick link to show how to distribute an in-house app to employees.

Comment: Thanks @Fogmeister..So i need to share 3000 employee device's UDID with apple..Is there any other solution for this problem.

Comment: there is no need of UDID of device for enterprise account. check my answer

Answer (score 0):

The application built with **enterprise license** will allow to install **on all iOS device**.

Simple share the IPA with all employee by your own web-link also.

> **but app should signed with in-house distribution provision file**

Comment: Thanks @CoolMonster, Before share an ipa file, i need to add device's UDID to provisioning profile ? is it..

Comment: no this provison file will never ask u to add udid while creating in developer portal. there is no restriction for this application, u can install it in any device.

Comment: I don't think it can install in any device without having provisioning profile.

Comment: http://www.apple.com/business/accelerator/deploy/app-distribution.html
proof. This is the way how i did for enterprise app.